# Correct way to design Knockout binding to wrap a jQuery plugin that assumes programmatic access to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, data-binding, knockout-3.0

Maybe I'm overthinking this, but I can't seem to come up with a clean way to wrap a jQuery plugin that assumes programmatic access to the DOM.  The plugin I'm trying to wrap is the [jQuery File Uploader plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).  To trigger a file upload programmatically, the plugin recommends calling the `.fileupload()` method on a jQuery selection like so:

```
$('#my-file-input-element').fileupload('send', {
    url: '/upload',
    done: function() {
        console.log('File upload complete');
    }
});
```

**How can I design a plugin that accomplishes this functionality without needing a reference to the original jQuery selection?**

My first thought is to have the custom binding attach a function to the ViewModel that can be called to trigger the upload.  So the binding might look something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fileUpload = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        viewModel.uploadFile = function() {
            $(element).fileupload('send', {
                url: '/upload',
                done: function() { 
                    console.log('File upload complete'); 
                }    
            });
        }
    }
}
```

(In a real implementation, I'd take the `url` and `done` parameters from a binding parameter instead of hardcoding them in the binding itself.)

Then in my ViewModel, I could call this new function:

```
function onSubmitButtonClicked() {
    uploadFile();
}
```

But this seems strange to me - I've never seen a Knockout binding augment a ViewModel like this.

Would this approach be consistent with Knockout's MVVM philosophy?  Is there a better way to accomplish this kind of behavior?

Comment: The custom binding could be bound to a `file` observable on the view model. When a `file` is selected and set on the observable, the `update` function of the custom binding will run in which you could call `.fileupload`.

Comment: @CrimsonChris How would I trigger the upload on a button click, for example?  I'd like to be able to trigger the upload from the ViewModel, not from the binding.

Comment: If your binding is set up to perform the file upload when the `file` observable is set, then in your button click you simply set the observable value.

Answer (score 0):

I created a generic 'widget' binding a while back that would allow you to pass just a name of a widget or a name and the widget options.

https://gist.github.com/osbornm/5043549

`<input type="file" data-bind="widget: 'fileUpload'"/>`

or

`<input type="file" data-bind="widget: {name: 'fileUpload', options:{'some': 'options'}"/>`